# Center Align Logo with CSS on Primer/Elementor Wordpress Site

Tags: css, wordpress, header, elementor

I would like to be able to adjust the logo on this site to place it in the center and add padding below it on mobile screens.

I am using this CSS currently without any luck:

```
.custom-logo {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The website is http://rayshvac.steveandsonslandscaping.com/

I don't even know where to start with using CSS just for mobile. Appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: add center to site-title-wrapper

Comment: Thank you! This worked. '.site-title-wrapper {
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
 padding-top: 30px;
}'